# I am traveling to Delhi, Aizawl and Mizoram in December. Is it necessary to take anti-malaria pills during this time of year?

Tags: india, health

I am traveling to Delhi, India for 6 days staying in a hotel, sight-seeing in a bus and then I will be in Aizawl and Mizoram, 7 days staying in hotels. I will be there from 12/27/2017 to 01/08/2018.

Is it necessary to take the anti-malaria pill of doxycycline or Malarone at this time of year?

Please advise. I've never been to India before. I have the typhoon vaccine and hepatitis A and B vaccines. Is there anything else I should obtain before going on this trip? Thank you.

Comment: Surely you mean the typhoid vaccination and not *typhoon* vaccine? Typhoon is a tropical cyclone.

Answer (score 1):

You should not really rely on advice from people on the internet about important matters like your health. Much better to look at websites like the US CDC advice for India [here](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/india) and follow their advice and that of your personal health advisors.

We do not know your age, sex or what country you will be entering India from all of which could affect the advice you are given.